# Loop and recursion: the difference in the number of repetitions

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

These two functions give the same result, but why there is "i > **4**" in the loop and "size > **5**" in the recursion? Why the numbers are different?

```
function branchBoxForLoop(size) {
  c.strokeStyle = "blue";
  for (var i = size; i > 4; i = i * 0.65) {
    c.translate(i, i);
    c.strokeRect(-i, -i, i, i);
  }
}
function branchBox(size) {
  c.translate(size, size);
  c.strokeRect(-size, -size, size, size);
  if (size > 5) {
    branchBox(size * 0.65);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They don't do the same for `All` inputs, but for some inputs.

Basically, the largest red flag here is that at the `recursion` function, you don't even check the `size` before executing `translate`and `strokeRect`, which means that it will always run atleast once.

A matched recursive function would be something like this (ignoring the `c.strokeStyle = "blue"`):

```
function branchBox(size) {
  if (size > 4) {
    c.translate(size, size);
    c.strokeRect(-size, -size, size, size);
    branchBox(size * 0.65);
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the functions actually behave essentially the same for size 7. You're right that it doesn't enter the function again in the recursion one, after hitting 4.55, but the kicker is that it doesn't NEED to enter it again, because the relevant functions `c.translate` and `c.strokeRect` are called BEFORE it checks if the number is > 5

Comment: I've posted an answer which lists all the values of Size which are different for the two functions. 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 19 and 20 are all in there, which makes me wonder why op ever thought they were the same...

Comment: @TKoL My bad, you are totally right, been a long day.. will soon edit the post. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

I made a way to test in bulk for matches and mismatches between the two functions:

```js
var c = {
    translate: () => {
        // console.log('translate arguments', arguments)
    },

    strokeRect: () => {
        // console.log('strokeRect arguments', arguments)
    }
}

function* branchBoxForLoop(size) {
  c.strokeStyle = "blue";
  for (var i = size; i > 4; i = i * 0.65) {
    c.translate(i, i);
    c.strokeRect(-i, -i, i, i);
    yield i;
  }
}
function* branchBox (size) {
  c.translate(size, size);
  c.strokeRect(-size, -size, size, size);
  yield size;
  if (size > 5) {
    yield* branchBox(size * 0.65);
  }
}

var matches = [];
var mismatches = [];
for (let x = 5; x < 100; x += 0.2) {
  x = x.toFixed(2);
  x = Number(x);
  let a = [...branchBoxForLoop(x)];
  let b = [...branchBox(x)];
  if (JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b)) {
    matches.push(x);
  } else {
    mismatches.push(x);
  }
}

console.log(mismatches);
```

[edit] the pattern is generally this

The two functions behave differently for

(a)every value above 5 that, when you multiply it by 0.65, produces a value less than 5

(b) And if you take all of those values from a and multiply them by (1/0.65), all those values ALSO behave differently

(c) And if you take all of those values from b and multiply them by (1/0.65), all those values ALSO behave differently

and so on, infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Actually they both will result different for input size = 4; code execution as below.

```
// branchBoxForLoop(4)
c.strokeStyle = "blue";


// branchBox(4)
c.translate(4, 4);
c.strokeRect(-4, -4, 4, 4);
```

For the same behaviour, will need to have consistent check.